# Updating SQL Server 2008 R2 using slipstreamed source

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to create a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 setup media. I have done this using slipstream method as recommended by Microsoft. I can only use this to create new installation. But is there a way I can use this media to update an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 instance?

Thanks in advance,

Dheena

Comment: For updating an existing instance you should use the SP1 install. Why do you want to use the slipstream media?

Comment: What is wrong with running the SP1 installer against the existing instance? That is the primary use of the SP1 installers, the ability to slipstream an SP into an existing set of install files is a secondary use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this. When you build the slipstreamed install, it is no longer an SP1 installer, it simply updates the files that the initial setup program uses during installation. It does not build an RTM installer and a separate SP1 installer that are somehow daisy-chained.

So I think the answer is: you will have to download SP1 again, and run it separately from any media where you have created a slipstreamed install.